# How to select the sum of distinct values in a table using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
slno state district company 
1     a       ab     abc
2     a       ab     ac
3     a       ab     abc
4     a       ab     abc
5     a       ab     abc
6     a       ab     ac
```

output

```
state district company sumzz
 a      ab       abc    4
 a      ab       ac     2
```

what i have tried

```
select state,district,company,sum(company) as sumzz from company
```

how to achieve this display the last row based on distinct company?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And what's wrong with this approach:

```
  SELECT state, district, company, COUNT(*) as countzz
    FROM company
GROUP BY state, district, company
```

Comment: The question says "display the last row based on distinct company?" but the example output matches your query, +1

Comment: But the example given does not show the last row (in 'ac' case).

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: For the updated question, you could retrieve the maximum `slno` in a subquery.  Then you can use `in` to filter for those:

```
select  state
,       district
,       company
,       slno
from    Company
where   slno in
        (
        select  max(slno)
        from    Company
        group by
                state
        ,       district
        ,       company
        )
```

Comment: I think that op wants to count rows, not actually suming

Comment: Oh, now that I read the updated question, I don't really know what op wants

Comment: @Lamak: You're probably right; the title suggests a third possible explanation, "sum distinct values"

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are trying to count how many records there are instead of suming something. If that is what you want, then you should be doing:

```
SELECT state, district, company, COUNT(*) as sumzz 
FROM company
GROUP BY state, district, company
```

Answer (score 0):

select state,district,company,sum(company) as sumzz from company where company = 'abc'

Comment: Why the `WHERE company = 'abc'`?, and where is the `GROUP BY`?

Comment: There is very little detail in the question and I interpreted "distinct company" to mean for one specific company. I did forget the group by clause though.

Comment: The expected output clearly shows records with company = 'ac'